# Conversion from 12 hour clock to 24 hour for sort awk

Tags: linux, awk, command-line-interface, gawk

From the command line using gawk or something similar on Linux, I would like to convert a 12 hour clock date/time to 24 hour clock for the purpose of sorting.

Sample data is

```
11/29/2016,9:42:21 AM
11/29/2016,12:42:26 PM
11/29/2016,12:42:27 PM
11/29/2016,12:42:50 PM
```

I got as far as this using the event log

```
cat  event_log.csv  |gawk -F \,  {'print $2'}
```

Thanks

Comment: The file name (event_log.csv) suggests that this is an event log file. I guess an event log file should be sorted time date/time already. What am I missing?

Comment: Note `cat event_log.csv  | any_utility`, unless you are *concatenating* two (or more) files, `cat file` is an *Unnecessary Use of `cat`* (*UUOc*) and should be avoided. Instead just read the file (e.g., `awk '...' file`) or use redirection (`utility < file`).

Answer (score 3):

Too bad you didn't include any values in your sample input that would actually be affected by this calculation but anyway, here's how you do it:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,:]' '
    ($5 == "AM") && ($2 == 12) { d = -12 }
    ($5 == "PM") && ($2 <  12) { d =  12 }
    { printf "%s,%02d:%s:%s\n", $1, $2 + d, $3, $4; d=0 }
' file
11/29/2016,09:42:21
11/29/2016,23:42:26
11/29/2016,12:42:27
11/29/2016,00:42:27
```

The above was run against this input file (modified from the OPs provided input to have values that would test the code):

```
$ cat file
11/29/2016,9:42:21 AM
11/29/2016,11:42:26 PM
11/29/2016,12:42:27 PM
11/29/2016,12:42:27 AM
```

Comment: This fail with `11/29/2016,12:42:27 AM` giving `11/29/2016,12:42:27`, it should give `11/29/2016,00:42:27`

Comment: @Jotne thanks for the heads up, I updated my answer.

Comment: Fixing old threads ;)

Answer (score -2):

Solved it

```
cat x.log | gawk '{cmd="date -d "$1 $2" +%H:%M:%S"; cmd | getline val; close(cmd); printf("%s\n",val) ; }'
```